# Sitecore Rocks: update only affects most recent item version

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-rocks

I'm using Sitecore Rocks to update a newly added field. However, with a workflow in place, only the latest version of each item is being updating. The hundreds of items in draft state are updated, but the published versions of those items are not getting updated.

Is there any way to construct the `from` or some other option I've missed to `update` all versions - or at least the publish version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The published versions are located in the Web database. To update those, you need to open the Query Analyzer in the Web database.

In the Master database, you can only update the latest version of an item. The Query Analyzer is based on the Sitecore Query language, which has been available since Sitecore 5. Unfortunately Sitecore Query only supports the latest version of an item.

Sorry.

Comment: Thanks. Updating the Web database was already done, but the next time the site was published, all my updates were erased.